# Can I disallow one particular data constructor inside another, while both give the same type?

Tags: haskell, types, gadt, data-kinds

I'd like to make a type `T` in Haskell that allows for

```
[Leaf 1, Rooted (Leaf 2), Branch (Leaf 3) (Branch (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5))]
```

but not

```
[Leaf 1, Rooted (Leaf 2), Branch (Rooted (Leaf 3)) (Branch (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5))]
```

ie. all constructors of `T` except `Rooted` can appear in the first or second arguments of `Branch` (the complete code has a few more constructors).

I've tried things like

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs #-}
data T (x::Bool) where
  Leaf :: Int -> T True
  Rooted :: T True -> T False
  Branch :: T True -> T True -> T True
```

which ensures we can't do `Branch (Rooted …) …` but also means we can't do `[Rooted …, One …]` since that would be a list of different types (`[T True, T False]`).

I looked into DataKinds, hoping I could do

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures #-}
data T where
  Leaf :: Int -> T
  Rooted :: T -> T
  Branch :: UnRooted a => a -> a -> T
class UnRooted a
instance UnRooted Leaf
instance UnRooted Branch
```

but then ghc (7.10.3) gives `Data constructor ‘Leaf’ comes from an un-promotable type ‘T’`.

Is there way to do this in Haskell?

Comment: If you want to put them in the same (homogeneous) list, you have to give the same type to root and non-root. But if they have the same type, you can substitute one for the other in subtrees. This is impossible, as stated. Perhaps it would be OK to wrap your first attempt into an existential wrapper so to remove the boolean in the type? Or using a sum type? Or, without GADTs, making root its own type (and still using a sum or wrapper)?

Comment: Can you explain why you want this? I.e., what the `Rooted` constructor is supposed to be *for*?

Comment: It's a pattern matcher. I'd like to be able to write expressions as simple lists, with fairly compact syntax. `Branch` is actually a set of operators to combine two expressions. `Rooted` is a (set of) wrappers to say things like "this pattern doesn't have to appear right next to the previous/next one". But it seems difficult to define this kind of type in a clean/simple way, so I guess I should find a different approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the first solution if you wrap everything in a constructor which hides the boolean value:

```
{-# LANGUAGE GADTs, DataKinds, KindSignatures, RankNTypes #-}
data T (x::Bool) where
  Leaf :: Int -> T True
  Rooted :: T True -> T False
  Branch :: T True -> T True -> T True

data TWrap = forall (x :: Bool). TWrap (T x)

[TWrap $ Leaf 1, TWrap $ Rooted (Leaf 2), TWrap $ Branch (Leaf 3) (Branch (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5))]
```

However, if we are going to have to wrap the type anyways, it's probably better to just go for the more straightforward solution of splitting the type:

```
data T = Leaf Int | Branch T T
data TWrap = Unrooted T | Rooted T

[Unrooted $ Leaf 1, Rooted $ Leaf 2, Unrooted $ Branch (Leaf 3) (Branch (Leaf 4) (Leaf 5))]
```

---

What you are asking for is basically [dependent types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependent_type), which Haskell doesn't have ([yet](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/ghc/wiki/DependentHaskell)).

Comment: Please correct me if my comment on dependent types was inaccurate. Haskell has some support for dependent types (e.g. through GADTs), but I believe more support would be needed to satisfy the description given in the question.